# how to disable CN checking for CXF 3.0.0+ jax-rs 2.0 client

Tags: ssl, certificate, cxf, jax-rs, cruisecontrol.net

I don't know how to programmatically disable CN checking with CXF 3.0.4 JAX-RS 2.0 client.  My code is as follows:

```html
     System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false"); 
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier( 
        new HostnameVerifier(){ 

            public boolean verify(String hostname, 
                    SSLSession sslSession) { 

                    return true; 
            
            } 
        }); 
            Client client = ClientBuilderImpl.newClient(); 
            String urlHost = "https://" + centralNode; 
            WebTarget target = client.target(urlHost).path(BASE_SERVICE_URL); 
            String encodedpw = Base64.encodeBase64String(passwd.getBytes()); 
            String body = "{\"uid\" : \"" + uid + "\",\"password\": \"" + encodedpw + "\"}"; 
            Response res = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

As you can see, I already tried to override the default hostnameverifier, and set jsse.enableSNIExtension to false.  None of these worked, i am still getting the exception:

"The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore. Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true."

Please help!

Comment: You are aware that disabling the host name check is effectively the same as disabling any kind of certificate validation, since now the attacker could use any certificate signed by a trusted CA instead of only the one matching the host name?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for this code snippet;

```
       HTTPConduit httpConduit=(HTTPConduit)ClientProxy.getClient(SAMPLE_PORT).getConduit();
       TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
       tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
       httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```

Always use this code in test environment.!

Comment: How should a SAMPLE_PORT look like? I'm new to this and need to try this out to get past this same issue